# Can't exit for-loop, seemingly stuck

Tags: c++

I recently picked up coding C++ and I was learning using Bjarne Stroustrup's introductory book, and I was presented with this code:

```
// simple dictionary: list of sorted words
int main() {
    vector<string> words;
    for(string temp; cin>>temp;) // read whitespace-separated words
        words.push_back(temp); // put into vector
    cout << "Number of words: " << words.size() << '\n';

    sort(words); // sort the words

    for (int i = 0; i < words.size(); ++i)
        if (i == 0 || words[i–1] != words[i]) // is this a new word?
            cout << words[i] << '\n';
}
```

That I replicated myself:

```
int main() {
    //variables.
    vector<string> dictionary;

    //prompts user to input words.
    cout << "input words in the dictionary:" << endl;
    while (dictionary.size() < 10) {
        for (string word; cin >> word;) {
            dictionary.push_back(word);
        }
    }
    //prints out number of words in the dictionary.
    cout << "number of words in the dictionary:" << dictionary.size() << endl;

    //sort the words and prints them out one by one, checking for repetitions.
    sort(dictionary.begin(), dictionary.end());
    for (int i = 0; i < dictionary.size(); ++i)
        if ((i == 0) || (dictionary[i-1] != dictionary[i]))
            cout << dictionary[i] << '\t';
    return 0;
}
```

But here's the problem, I can't exit the initial loop of inserting words inside the dictionary (the while loop I added was to try to fix it, but it seemingly doesn't work either).

Thank you for your time :).

Comment: What do you think would be a condition evaluating to `false` here; `for (string word; cin >> word;)`?

Comment: Does the code work if used exactly as in the book, i.e. without any change? Did you double check that the code in the book and the first shown code are 100% identical?

Comment: Does the text not provide any hint about how to exit the loop? (You need to terminate the input stream.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The inner for loop will run until `cin >> word`  is `false` which might not be the case if you keep adding valid strings. Moreover you do not need an extra while wrapping the `for-loop`. You can just do something like below or add a `break` statement when necessary.

```
for (string word; cin >> word && dictionary.size() <10;) {
    dictionary.push_back(word);
 }
```

Comment: The inner loop is not always true. It will terminate when EOF is read from `cin` (such as pressing Ctrl+D on most Linuxes).

Comment: Then please reword it somehow. As the answer currently stands, it's incorrect.